# How to check whether a container is stable

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

`std::vector` is an unstable container, i.e. by resizing the vector, iterators might become invalidated.
In contrast, `std::list` or `boost::container::stable_vector` are stable containers which keep the iterators valid until the removal of the corresponding element.

Is there a way to check whether a given container is stable? For instance, if I have something like

```
template<template <typename A, typename B=std::allocator<A> > class T=std::list>
class Foo
{
}
```

Is it possible to allow only for stable containers and forbid the unstable ones?

Comment: This is why we need concepts! (I think)

Comment: @MarkGarcia: This is why we need *axioms*, in fact. Concepts without axioms cannot capture such semantic requirements. I'm not sure we will have them soon, though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is anything available providing such information, but you could write your own trait. However, you will need to specialize it for every stable container that may be used, which is perhaps not an option.

```
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template <template <typename...> class Container>
struct is_stable
    : std::false_type
{};

template <>
struct is_stable<std::list>
    : std::true_type
{};

template <>
struct is_stable<boost::container::stable_vector>
    : std::true_type
{};

template<template <typename...> class Container = std::list>
class Foo
{
    static_assert(is_stable<Container>::value, "Container must be stable");
};

int main()
{
    Foo<std::list> f1; // ok
    Foo<std::vector> f2; // compiler error
}
```

I don't think there is a way you can automatically detect that a container is stable, without resorting to manual specialization.

---

Just for fun, I tried writing what the concept/axiom for stability would look like ([concepts](http://www.devx.com/SpecialReports/Article/38864) and [axioms](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/concept-axioms-what-for/) are an extension to the language that were [considered for inclusion in C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2081.pdf)):

```
concept StableGroup<typename C, typename Op>
    : Container<C>
{
    void operator()(Op, C, C::value_type);

    axiom Stability(C c, Op op, C::size_type index, C::value_type val)
    {
        if (index <= c.size())
        {
            auto it = std::advance(c.begin(), index);
            op(c, val);
            return it;
        }
        <->
        if (index <= c.size())
        {
            op(c, val);
            return std::advance(c.begin(), index);
        }
    }
}
```

If think this correctly captures the requirement that every iterator over the original container is equivalent to the corresponding iterator over the modified container. Not sure this is very useful, but coming up with such axioms is an interesting exercise :)!

Comment: This is absolutely correct -- stable/unstable is very much an abstract idea. A vector may easily not invalidate its iterators: may not resize the array when you think it does or even if it does, it may be able to extend the existing memory block it uses (depending on the compiler etc.). If I write my own container, it could easily non-deterministically reallocate memory.

Comment: This trait breaks if you don't include the header with `boost::stable_vector`, for example. To be generaly usable, you'd also need to forward declare all the classes you're specializing it for.

Comment: @jrok: Yes, this is why this solution is far from ideal. Ideally, it would be the responsibility of container libraries to specialize the trait, but this is obviously not an option. Another possibility is to leave the trait unspecialized (apart from the most common containers) and indicate to `Foo` users that if they wish to use another container, they must specialize the trait: the `static_assert` will draw their attention to this part of the documentation, that should make it very clear that the container must be stable. Still not very convenient, though.