# Genenal solution for modifying while iterate over c++ containers?

Tags: c++, iterator

There are various occations where  modifying while iterate over c++ containers is required.

Like when callbacks are stored in a `std::list`, when iterate over and calling these callbacks, the `std::list` may need to be modified.

But this is not safe out of box.Is there any general solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: In order for a container to be modifiable during iteration, it needs to be what is called stable.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709828/how-to-check-whether-a-container-is-stable

Comment: Show your code, we could help you to do that. Your problem seem to be XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes i need to remove items from the container while iterating.
with c++11 (erase return the next iterator) you can do like this code.

```
  std::vector<MyClass> vector;
  std::vector<MyClass>::iterator it;
  for(it=vector.begin();it!=vector.end();)
  {
    if(it->removeFromList())
    {
      it=vector.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
      it->doSomething();
      ++it;
    } 
  }
```

**How do you want to edit the container exactly?**

Comment: It's not the purpose of `for` loop, use a `while` loop to do that. Indent your code with space.